# How to define method to return related objects

Tags: python, django

I have two models:

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, null=True)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=500)

    def pets(self):
        return Pet.objects.filter(owner=self.id)

class Pet(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey(Profile)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=150)
```

I want to access to pets over profile class. When I call `profile.pets` on terminal, the response is:

```
 <bound method Profile.pets of <Profile: sefa>
```

how to I get pets for a profile object?

Comment: You don't need a method, `profile.pet_set.all()` is defined for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`profile.pets` is a method.

You have to call it

```
pets = profile.pets()
```

Comment: You also can acces attributes from the fk field  itself `pet = Pet.object.first(); print pet.owner.pk`

Answer (score 1):

```
profile = Profile.objects.get(id=id_of_profile_you_want)
list_of_pets = profile.pet_set
```